# how to dynamically add labels to my checklist in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, checkboxlist

I want to populate my checklist from an array dynamically. How should I populate the values and labels for this checklist using jquery/javascript?

```
<div class="container" id="check">
    <input type="checkbox" value= array[0]/> <label></label>
    <input type="checkbox" value= array[1]/> <label></label>
    <input type="checkbox" value= array[2]/> <label></label>
</div>
```

How to populate the label tag with the elements of the array?

Comment: where is that array comes from.? Show the relevant JS.

Comment: i already had that array.. Anyways, the problem got solved... I used the answer mentioned by rakhi4110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the array come from?
If you have the array available already in your JS, then you can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
    $('#check label').each(function(index){
        if(index < arr.length)
            $(this).text(arr[index]);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example,

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var array = [1, 2, 3];
        var i = 0;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function (current) {
            alert($(this).val(array[i]));
            i++;

        });
    });
```